# How to extract elements in an array according to some boundaries in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like x = [3, 5, 6, 11, 18, 24, 29]
I want to extract the elements which are greater than 5 and less than or equal to 24 from x.

How can i do that?

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with and someone will probably help you

Answer (score 3):

```
x = [3, 5, 6, 11, 18, 24, 29]
selected = [i for i in x if i>5 and i<=24]
print(selected)
```

Comment: Chain comparison will be more Pythonic: `5 < i <= 24`

Answer (score 1):

If you use/prefer numpy, you can use np.where():

```
x[np.where((x > 5) & (x <= 24))]
```

or just:

```
x[(x > 5) & (x <= 24)]
```

result:

```
array([ 6, 11, 18, 24])
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is to extract all the elements/numbers that are greater than 5 and less than 24, you'll have to use for/while loops.

for your problem it's best to use a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), so the code will look something like this:

```
x = [3, 5, 6, 11, 18, 24, 29]
new_lst = []

for number in x:
    if number > 5 and number < 24:
        new_lst.append(number)
```

You can read about the [.append()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp) function here.